# trying to call a perl script from python, resulting in weird behaviour

Tags: python, perl, subprocess

I am trying to call a perl script from my python program with the following line:

```
subprocess.call(r'/path/to/compute_lexrank.pl /path/to/11sent',shell=True)
```

when I run the same perl script from the shell (just typing `/path/to/compute_lexrank.pl /path/to/11sent`) it works fine as expected, but when I run it from the python program, the perl script is executed, but gives a mysterious error:

```
Math::MatrixReal::new(): number of rows must be integer > 0 at /Users/filippo/Downloads/clairlib-core-1.08/lib//Clair/Network.pm line 1628
```

now because I havent wrote the perl script myself I dont know how to fix this, but why the same script behaves differently when I run it from the shell or from subprocess.call?

I am using MacOsX, python 2.6 (but I have tried also with 2.5, same stuff) and perl 5.10.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Check your environment. There's a high probability your are getting different versions of Perl.

Comment: how can I do that? I specified #!/usr/bin/perl -w at the beginning of the perl script, how can I check what version of perl is used? thanks

Comment: `perl -e 'print "$]\n";'` should do the trick.

Comment: I'have added a print "$]\n"; to the perl file, in both cases it prints out 5.010000

Comment: Is the Python program running as the same user as when you invoke the Perl script from the command line?  Is it possible that the Perl script is failing to open /path/to/11sent due to a permissions problem?  Does the Perl script check to make sure its file open is succeeding?

Comment: mmh I tried running the python script from the same command line (is that enough to ensure that they are invoked with the same user?), and also giving a chmod a+rxw 11sent.txt, but it doesnt seems to make any difference. I am not sure if the perl script fails to load the file as I dont understand it very much, it was given to me

Comment: How big is the script? Can you post it here?

Comment: uhm it is pretty big as it is spread over several files and libraries, I am not sure what is calling as I said

Comment: I think we're out of gas then.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, there's a good rule: if possible, use list forms of `popen` and `system`. Python seems to have those, too. I wonder what happens if you try this out:

```
helper = "/path/to/compute_lexrank.pl"
helper_input = "/path/to/11sent"
subprocess.call([helper, helper_input])
```

Comment: I just tried, it is still the same error. I can't understand the difference between executing the script from the shell or from inside python

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pass the working directory to the subprocess.call

```
subprocess.call(r'/path/to/compute_lexrank.pl /path/to/11sent',shell=True,cwd="/path/to")
```

> If cwd is not None, the child’s current directory will be changed to cwd before it is executed. Note that this directory is not considered when searching the executable, so you can’t specify the program’s path relative to cwd.